# "Cannot find module errors" when using docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to learn how to understand node containers within a docker-compose environment.

I've built a simple docker container using a nodejs alpine base container.  My container has a simple hello world express server.  This container has been pushed to the public docker hub repo, [zipzit/node-web-app](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/zipzit/node-web-app)

- Container works great from the command line, via `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d zipzit/node-web-app`
- Function verified via browser at http://localhost:49160
- After the command line above is run, I can shell into the running container via `$ docker exec -it <container_id> sh`
- I can look at the directories within the running docker container, and see my server.js, package.json files, etc...
- From what I can tell, from the command line testing, everything seems to be working just fine.

Not sure why, but this is a total fail when I try to use this in a docker-compose test.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    nginx-proxy:
        # http://blog.florianlopes.io/host-multiple-websites-on-single-host-docker
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
        container_name: nginx-proxy
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
        restart: always

    mongo_db:
        image: mongo
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        volumes:
            - ./data:/data/db
        restart: on-failure:8
        environment:
          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mongo_password

    react_frontend:
        image: "zipzit/node-web-app"
        ## working_dir: /usr/src/app     ## remarks on / off here testing all the combinations
        ## environment:
        ##    - NODE_ENV=develop
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
            - ./frontend:/usr/src/app

    backend_server:
        ## image: "node:current-alpine3.10"
        image: "zipzit/node-web-app"
        user: "node"
        working_dir: /usr/src/app
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=develop
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
          - ./backend:/usr/src/app
          - ./server_error_log:/usr/src/app/error.log
        links:
          - mongo_db
        depends_on:
          - mongo_db

volumes:
    frontend: {}
    backend: {}
    data: {}
    server_error_log: {}
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d`, and then let things settle, the two containers based on zipzit/node-web-app start to run and immediately shut down.

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                                      NAMES
92710df9aa89        zipzit/node-web-app   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 seconds ago       Exited (1) 5 seconds ago                                              root_react_frontend_1
48a8abdf02ca        zipzit/node-web-app   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 minutes ago       Exited (1) 5 seconds ago                                              root_backend_server_1
27afed70afa0        jwilder/nginx-proxy   "/app/docker-entrypo…"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes              0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   nginx-proxy
b44344f31e52        mongo                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes              0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                   root_mongo_db_1
```

When I go to `docker logs <container_id>` I see:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:903
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:900:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:745:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:72:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

When I check out the `frontend` volume, its totally blank.  No server.js file, nothing.

Note: I'm running the docker-compose stuff on a Virtual Private Server (VPS) Ubuntu server.  I built the container and did my command line testing on a Mac laptop with docker.  Edit: I went back and did complete `docker-compose up -d` testing on the laptop with exactly the same errors as observed in the Virtual Private Server.

I don't understand what's happening here.  Why does that container work from the command line but not via docker-compose?

Comment: I'm also suspicious of the volumes that overwrite the images' `/usr/src/app` directories, especially where you talk about deploying to a VPS that wouldn't necessarily have the source code on it.  Does deleting these `volumes:` lines improve things?

Comment: If I delete `volumes:` from within the `react_frontend:` portion of the docker-compose.yml file, then the container is stable and functional.  I know I can SSH / `docker exec -it <node_app> sh` and get to the content of interest, but I'd prefer a functional volume bind, similar to what I see in the mongo_db container.

Comment: So I'm still searching... Here's a [pretty good reference...](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)   It seems volumes must be defined when the container is created, and that info is part of the metadata of the container.  e.g. try `$ docker inspect zipzit/node-web-app` and compare those results with `$ docker inspect mongo`.  Look at the `volumes:` object callout in container config info.

Comment: And here's [another good reference...](https://blog.container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker)

Comment: any solution? have the same error

Answer (score 0):

You are binding volumes in `./frontend` or `./backend` with the same image running the following command:

[CMD ["node" "server.js"]](https://hub.docker.com/layers/zipzit/node-web-app/latest/images/sha256-a9cecf358bcd5c6818a7044016a4c9a2f6e85fb36b5c0bd7b05502f571e55367?context=explore)

Are you sure this is the right command ? Are you sure there is a `server.js` in each folder mounted on your host ?

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was the intent. One container image, cloned twice= two running containers, as indicated above.  I can go back and test with just one.  As the container won't stay running, I can't SSH (docker exec) inside.  And both of those volume directories are absolutely blank.  My understanding is that the volume is a two way "clone" to what's inside the docker container.

Comment: I removed the entire backend_server content from docker-compose.yml and retested. 
 The frontend still fails `Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/server.js' `

Comment: When you're building the image with `docker-compose build`, your Dockerfile run instructions like `COPY` or `ADD` to copy external ressources into a "temporary layer image" which contains the files. At the end of the build process, all layers are merged into a single image. When you're binding a container volume with your host folder, the data in container will not appear in your host folder. So if the `./frontend` folder is empty, the command can't find the `server.js` file. So you have to remove the volumes instructions in your `docker-compose.yml` file and double check folders content.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're trying to mount local paths into your containers, but you're then declaring those paths as `volume`s in the compose file.

The simple solution is to **remove the volumes section** of your compose file.

[Here's the reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) - it's not very clear from the docs but basically when you mount a volume, `docker-compose` first looks for that volume in the `volumes` section, and if it is present uses that volume. The name of the volume is not treated as a local path in this scenario, it is an ID of a volume that is then created on the fly (and will be empty). If however the volume is not declared in `volumes`, then it is treated as a local path and mounted as such.

Comment: So, no, a volume is not a two way clone.. Let me test this..

Comment: Did a bunch of testing. You are right, the whole bottom `volumes` portion of the docker-compose.yml file was redundant.  But this is still a fail.  No server.js file is found.  Data stuff from Mongo works great. No go on frontend or backend. Those 2 containers start up, and and then close within seconds.  Same error as above.  When you ran this on your system, what did you see?  Copy, save as `docker-compose.yml`, `docker-compose up -d` and go...

Comment: Compose looks at the syntax of the `volumes:`.  A source path of `./frontend` is always a host-directory bind mount, even if there happens to be a volume named `frontend` in the top-level `volumes:` section.

Comment: David, is that a one way bind, or a two way bind?  Looking at the MongoDB container, and the generated data directory, I'm assuming it goes in both directions.  The host container directory (data, frontend, backend,...) is a clone of the directory that exists within that individual container.  And removing the `volumes` did not correct the deficiency.  The container still fails.

Comment: At startup time, the volume content completely hides whatever was in the image.  Writes to the mounted directory after that will be reflected in the volume or host directory, depending on what was mounted.  In particular, if you bind mount an empty host directory over something important in the image, it will be empty when the container starts up.  The container needs explicit code to populate the directory (most of the Docker Hub database images will create an empty database in their entrypoint scripts).

Comment: See comment on original question.